# In what collections have the books of the Time Quintet been released?

Tags: a-wrinkle-in-time, madeleine-lengle

This month's topic challenge is Madeleine L'Engle's *Time Quintet*.  However, although I was a fan of L'Engle's books as a child, I knew nothing of a "*Time Quintet*" until I was an adult.  Rather, when I was in elementary school, circa 1985, I received a boxed set edition of "*The Time Trilogy*."

[image: The Time Trilogy Boxed Set]

Moreover, [the Wikipedia page for the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Quintet) lists (in spite of its "*Time Quintet*" title) **eight** books in the series.

*A Wrinkle in Time* (1962)
*The Arm of the Starfish* (1965)
*Dragons in the Waters* (1967)
*A Wind in the Door* (1973)
*A Swiftly Tilting Planet* (1978)
*A House Like a Lotus* (1984)
*Many Waters* (1986)
*An Acceptable Time* (1989)

This leads me to my question:  What different collections have there been of these books?  Lots of other juxtapositions could have been possible over time.  The only consistent connection among the books is that the main characters are all members of Meg Murry-O'Keefe's family.  In the introduction to *A Wind in the Door*, L'Engle even specifically says that the book is not a "sequel" to *A Wrinkle in Time*, since it tells a completely unrelated story.

Answer (score 6):

The various Wrinkle in Time books have been repeatedly collected, usually (but not always) with the first three books in the series.

- [***The Time Trilogy (Boxed Set)***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?308345) (1979) with *A Wrinkle in Time*, *A Wind in the Door* and *A Swiftly Tilting Planet*.
- [***The Time Quartet (Boxed Set)***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?48642) (1991) with *A Wrinkle in Time*, *A Wind in the Door* and *A Swiftly Tilting Planet* and *Many Waters*.
- [***The Time Quartet***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?407161) (2003) (also Published as The Wrinkle in Time Quartet) with *A Wrinkle in Time*, *A Wind in the Door* and *A Swiftly Tilting Planet* and *Many Waters*.
- [***A Wrinkle in Time Trilogy***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?396278) (2012 + [2015](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?622782)) with *A Wrinkle in Time*, *A Wind in the Door* and *A Swiftly Tilting Planet*.
- *[**The Wrinkle in Time Quintet**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?396712)* ([2007](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wrinkle-Time-Quintet-Madeleine-Engle/dp/0312373511/ref=sr_1_11?crid=19N2BYINOFB7Q&keywords=Madeleine%20L%27Engle%20collection&qid=1659938511&s=books&sprefix=madeleine%20l%20engle%20%2Cstripbooks%2C1677&sr=1-11) + 2012 + 2013) with *A Wrinkle in Time*, *A Wind in the Door*, *A Swiftly Tilting Planet*, *An Acceptable Time* and *Many Waters*.
- [***The Wrinkle in Time Quartet***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?749481) (2018) with *A Wrinkle in Time*, *A Wind in the Door* and *A Swiftly Tilting Planet* and *Many Waters*.
- [***The Polly O'Keefe Quartet***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?749482) (2018) with *The Arm of the Starfish*, *Dragons in the Waters*, *A House Like a Lotus* and *An Acceptable Time*.
- [***Madeleine L'Engle: The Kairos Novels: The Wrinkle in Time and Polly O'Keefe Quartets (Library of America Boxed Set)*** (2018)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Madeleine-lEngle-Wrinkle-Quartets-Library/dp/1598535773/ref=sr_1_1?crid=19N2BYINOFB7Q&keywords=Madeleine%20L%27Engle%20collection&qid=1659938511&s=books&sprefix=madeleine%20l%20engle%20%2Cstripbooks%2C1677&sr=1-1) with *A Wrinkle in Time*, *A Wind in the Door*, *A Swiftly Tilting Planet*, *Many Waters*, *The Arm of the Starfish*, *Dragons in the Waters*, *A House Like a Lotus* and *An Acceptable Time*.